# Is the code in a Promise referring to the variables at the loop iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I've got a general question about Promises in JS.
I couldn't find a solution to my answer and finally decided to ask here.

So let's look at the following pseudo-code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    some_promise(function(){
        console.log(i);

        // Would this i return the value of some_promise point of execution, 
        // or at the current iteration when it is triggered?
    });
}
```

If we look at the first iteration and the promise is triggered, would it be 0 or let's say 1000(Iterations moving on while waiting for promise)

It would be really helpful if you could help me wrap my head around it..

Comment: Why not try it out yourself? And what does `some_promise` do? It seems like this has nothing to do with promises.

Comment: It depends if some_promise fires immeadiately or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `let` the console.log will fire 10000 times and its one will have the value of `i` in the loop.

Example:

```
const fun = function(){

  var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  })

  for(let i=0; i<1000; i++){
     promise.then(() => console.log(i));
  }

}
```

If you use `var` the console.log will fire 10000 printing `10000` as value:

```
const fun = function(){

  var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  })

  for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
     promise.then(() => console.log(i));
  }

}
```

That's because var is scoped to the nearest function block and let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block, your loop is synchronous and will fire at least on "tick" before the promise is resolved.

Comment: Thank You! That's actually quite annoying, as I don't have a way to work with the index in my promises... Thanks anyways!! :)

Comment: @CrypticPug :))